# Как сделать такие поля ввода на HTML + CSS

Tags: css, html-form

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот все до чего я додумался

```
<input type="number" value="10.000" placeholder="Бюджет*:">
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```html
<style>
        .input-wrapper {
            border: #dddddd 1px solid;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 10px 5px;
            width: 200px;
            color: #dddddd;
        }
        .some-input {
            background-color: white;
            border: 0;
            width: 100px    ;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        Бюджет*: 
        <input class="some-input" type="text">
    </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Вот на div'ах с flebox'ом решение:

```css
.parent {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
}

.my-button {
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #e4eafa;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    font-size: 11px;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
.my-button>span {
      color: #d0dbf7;
    }

.my-button>input {
      color: #31384b;
      outline: 0;
      border: 0;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      width: 75px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="my-button">
    <span>Бюджет*:</span>
    <input name=budget value="10.000р" />
  </div>

  <div class="my-button">
    <span>Просмотры*:</span>
    <input name=budget value="100.000" />
  </div>
</div>
```